# How to dereference a variable in CSH

Tags: shell, variables, interpolation, csh, tcsh

I have a variable $var that has values as another variable $env .
$env has some value . how can I use $var to print the value of $env.

```
> set xyz = 'abc' set env = 'xyz' set v = '$' set var = "$v""$env"
> 
> echo $var    o/p: $xyz
```

now I want to print the value the of $ xyz using $var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eval`, like this:

```
set xyz='abc'
set var='xyz'
eval echo \$$var
```

This is more commonly known as an *indirect reference*.

---

Here is an example script:

```
set var = 'xyz'
set xyz = 'abc'
if ( $?var ) then
    echo '$var is set to '"$var"
endif
if ( $?xyz ) then
    echo '$xyz is set to '"$xyz"
endif
if ( `eval echo \$\?$var` ) then
    echo '$$var is set to '`eval echo \$$var`
endif
```

Output:

```
> csh test
$var is set to xyz
$xyz is set to abc
$$var is set to abc
```

Comment: this solution did not work unfortunately :(                      O/p : 11208var: Command not found

Comment: Reset your shell and edit your question to show me exactly the steps you tried. Artifacts from your previous attempts may be affecting your case.

Comment: the above mentioned solution will work for Bash  while I am using Csh.

Comment: I've been using `csh` and pretty much _only_ `csh` for 5+ years now, due to my company having based all its infrastructure on it. I tested the above on `csh`. I did `which csh` to make sure `csh` wasn't mapped to `tcsh` or something else, too.

Comment: I also did which csh its  /bin/csh .

Comment: how can I put eval in if statement ?

Comment: Use backticks, `\`eval ...\``.

Comment: is there any way if I can check if xyz is defined or not in the above example ?

Comment: Yes, in `csh` the syntax to check if `$xyz` is defined is `if ( $?xyz )` (or `if ( !( $?xyz ) )`).

Comment: I need to use variable var to check if xyz is defined or not , how can this be done ?

Comment: Try `if ( \`eval echo \$?$var\` )`.

Comment: Sorry, correction. You'll need a backslash on the `?` too. Try `if ( \`eval echo \$\?$var\` )`

Comment: Glad to hear! Happy coding.