# Does csh have pointer?

Tags: pointers, csh

Im using csh (c-shell) and I dont know that if csh support pointer?
for example:

```
set a = 1
set b = a
echo $($b)
=> 1
```

I mean `$($b)` => `$a` (replace `$b` by `a`)

Could you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dereference a variable in CSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997629/how-to-dereference-a-variable-in-csh)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I find the answer for my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/csh
set a=1
set b=a
eval echo \$$b
```

so the $ will dereference $b to a to give 1